# Отключение событий на хостинге. Что делать?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, события, веб-сервер, хостинг

Доброго дня/утра/вечера.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать, если на хостинге отключили события в mysql (phpMyAdmin). Сделали это внезапно, и получилась крайне неприятная ситуация. Включать события они не собираются, поэтому нужно найти альтернативное решение (например, как каждую секунду уменьшать данные в таблице на определённое значение). CRON имеет минимальный интервал 10 минут, а бесконечные циклы не работают.

Comment: Крон может работать и каждую секунду.

Comment: На хостинге видимо введено ограничение

Comment: что значит бесконечные циклы не работают? тайлимит скрипту ставите в 0 и все будет нормально раблтать.